# HQL suitable query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

[image]

Hello, I use hibernate HQL queries, let's say I have 3 Classes which are related one to other like it's shown in the diagram below, and I want to select "Bonc"s where "ItemsMateriel"= a number, what should I do ?? I tried this way

```
public List SelectBzzouitemmateriel (int i)
    {
             Query q =em.createQuery("select bc from Bonc bc inner join bc.selecteditems inner join bc.selecteditems.itemmateriel where bc.selecteditems.itemmateriel.iditemsmateriel = :i");
             q.setParameter("iditemsmateriel", i);

             return   (List) q.getResultList();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joined entities may have aliases too:

```
select bc from Bonc bc join bc.selecteditems si where si.itemmateriel.iditemsmateriel = :i
```

Also, you don't need explicit join to follow one-to-one relationship.

Comment: I tried this way but it tells me "org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [iditemsmateriel]"